Declare, initialise and use in a single command
I am currently optimising a huge application written in C++ created before a decade and maintained by many people. It has number of messages and fields to communicate to outside world. Whenever need arises new field is added to the message(s). It is also manually maintain in a static array (just for information).
Something like this
typedef struct {
   int id;
   char name[10];
   int value;
} Field;

typedef struct {
   char name[20];
   Field fields[100];
   int noOfFields;
} Storage;

Storage stor[] = { {"Store One",
                   {{1,"FieldA",97},
                    {2,"FieldB",95},
                    {3,"FieldC",23}}, <-------------------- added field 
                   3},
                  {"Store Two",
                   {{4,"FieldAA",45},
                    {5,"FieldAC",52}},
                   2},
                  {"Store Three",
                   {{0,"",0}},
                   0}
                };

From the above sample say FieldC with default value 23 is needed in number of messages. Then it need to be added using function, like below, in messages to send and also in the static Storage array above.
MessageASend(....)
{
...
AddField("FieldC",23,xx,xx,xx)           /*non-relevant parameters are marked with xx*/
...
}

MessageBSend(....)
{
...
AddField("FieldC",23,xx,xx,xx)
...
}


The static array can be printed like below just for information to know the available fields.
void printContent(int stNo)
{
   printf("Store #:%d name:%s field:%d\n",stNo,stor[stNo].name,stor[stNo].noOfFields);
   for(auto fld:stor[stNo].fields) {
      if (!fld.id)
         break;
      printf("field:[ %d,%s,%d ]\n",fld.id,fld.name,fld.value);
   }
   printf("-------------------\n");
}

The issue is the static array is not seriously maintained. There are fields in messages but not in the static array. Also fields removed from messages are not removed from static array.
I need a solution that not rely on developer to maintain the static array manually. Preferably when someone calls a new field AddField it should be added to the array automatically. Preferably a single line call for the coders. It can be a macro or template
Say something like ADDFIELD() function/macro that can call AddField and add to statics array. Then I can replace all AddField with this at one shot
The array initialisation has to be at compile time.

Unrelated: The old code looks to be written by C devs. Since you're already making changes, I would recommend also making it more C++ by replacing the typedefs and instead using normal struct with names. I see that you're alerady using c++11, so you can use c++11 features.

I also think a [mcve] is needed for this as currently it isn't clear to me what is the expected output. And this also seem to be of a design issue perhaps?

@user12002570, i am open to C++11 features if it help here otherwise I dont want to rock the boat too much. Your probably right there seems to be a design flaw but i dont think I can venture into making drastic changes. There are hundreds of fields and message are there.

No this is not "C++" code it is "C" code. Question before you begin changing stuff, do you have unit and integration tests?

You are basically designing protocol buffers. Assuming you can't actually switch over to real protobuf (e.g. you need to maintain wire format for backward compatibility), you can at least borrow their main idea: the structure of the message is described in a separate file using language invented just for that purpose; then C++ code (as well as code in other programming langauges) is generated from that file. Define your own message description language, write a script to generate C++ code from it. So you change the fields in one place and all code stays in sync.
